# Enzym doesn't seem to read updated state of a React component correctly

Tags: reactjs, components, state, jestjs, enzyme

I test a React component:

```
onDateSelect(newDate) {
    const date = moment(this.state.date);
    const { day, month, year } = newDate;

    date.date(day);
    date.month(month-1);
    date.year(year);

    this.setState({
        date,
        value: date.format(DATE_FORMAT)
    });
}
```

with:

```
test('Method onDateSelect', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<DatePickerField date={ moment('2022-11-22') } />)

    wrapper.instance().onDateSelect({ day: 23, month: 11, year: 2022 });  // Run it once because of an issue with testing moment in Jest

    expect(wrapper.state().date).toBe(moment('2022-11-23'));
})
```

Jest returns an error, though there is non:

> ```
> Expected value to be (using ===):
>   "2022-11-22T23:00:00.000Z"
> Received:
>   "2022-11-21T23:00:00.000Z"
>
> Difference:
>
> - Expected
> + Received
>
> - "2022-11-22T23:00:00.000Z"
> + "2022-11-21T23:00:00.000Z"
> ```

I'm in CET time zone, so it shows one hour earlier on both. But still enzyme state contains the old value. The function is working fine though.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call an instance method and interact with the state, you need to use [mount](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/mount.html) and not `shallow`

Comment: I can't use mount :-(